# CRM 2011 - A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

one day we have met a problem with connecting to the CRM server from outside. When we tried to use web service for the communication with the CRM or use some Microsoft utilities, like crmsvcutil.exe the server returned the following error:

Exiting program with exception: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.

When we used CRM WS it seemed, that for the first query it worked correctly and returned the data. However when we put another query it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this can also be if you try to return an `IEnumerable` of something from a service to a client.

Enumerate it first (basically call `ToList()`) to ensure all data is retrieved before the program flow moves on and the connection is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

We have found the following solution which can be useful for you:

The problem has been in the settings of the CRM on the IIS. Open the IIS and disable "HTTP keep-alive" option (CRM web site -> HTTP Response Headers -> Set Common Headers… in Action panel) - http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/did-you-know-enable-http-keep-alive-in-iis-7-75.aspx

If you can't disable the keep alive option for the whole CRM, you can update your code which uses CRM web service (disable keep alive settings in the code) - http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2004/01/28/63771.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if IFD is enabled then we need to check w.r.t WPC Token expiration.